# Nagios (re-)send notification for service in OK state

Tags: nagios

Quite simple question: How could I set re-sending notifications in Nagios for service which doesn't change its state?

I want to use it for fake sms. Service is allways OK (the whole script content is exit 0 ) and I want every day notification about it.

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: get SMS every day in 6AM and 6PM with info: service fakesms ... is OK

Comment: Everything I thought of so far (volatile service, event handlers) is about state changes or non-OK states. Seriously, why don't you just use cron? Nagios is obviously the wrong tool here.

Comment: @KarmaFusebox so you think it couldn't be done via Nagios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible within any Nagios Object.
Nagios goes to great lengths to track state change and not much more.

What you can do is make a custom service that triggers a notification
every day.

All in all though it sounds pretty useless. If you haven't got a notification for
a changing state, it's safe to assume that your service is in its initial state.

Answer (score 1):

**You are trying to use Nagios in a way that it's not been designed for** and contradicts general UNIX philosophy:

*"No news are good news"* or *"Don't bother me unless something is going wrong"*.

You should think about what you're trying to accomplish, and if it's the proper way to do. If so, you need to develop your own solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`notification_interval`, from the top of my head.

Comment: I thought this too, but there is Object definition: This directive is used to define the number of "time units" to wait before re-notifying a contact that this service is still DOWN or UNREACHABLE. - but I need this service to be OK

Answer (score -1):

Notification on Email

Sample configuration files have now been installed in the /usr/local/nagios/etc directory. These sample files should work fine for getting started with Nagios. You'll need to make just one change before you proceed...
Edit the /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/contacts.cfg config file with your favorite editor and change the email address associated with the nagiosadmin contact definition to the address you'd like to use for receiving alerts.

vi /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/contacts.cfg

Comment: Thanks for negative voting but please suggest what i am doing wrong?? I used this its worked for me